# How to convert the integer values to lacs or crores (Indian numbering system)

Tags: php, php-5.6

I want to convert the integer value to [Indian Numbering system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system). I am giving the value 540000 as input and getting the output value 5.4 Lac, but I want answer 5.40 Lac.

My Code:

```
<?php
function no_to_words($no)
{
    if($no == 0) {
        return ' ';

    }else {
        $n =  strlen($no); // 7
        switch ($n) {
            case 3:
                $val = $no/100;
                $val = round($val, 2);
                $finalval =  $val ." Hundred";
                break;
            case 4:
                $val = $no/1000;
                $val = round($val, 2);
                $finalval =  $val ." Thousand";
                break;
            case 5:
                $val = $no/1000;
                $val = round($val, 2);
                $finalval =  $val ." Thousand";
                break;
            case 6:
                $val = $no/100000;
                $val = round($val, 2);
                $finalval =  $val ." Lac";
                break;
            case 7:
                $val = $no/100000;
                $val = round($val, 2);
                $finalval =  $val ." Lac";
                break;
            case 8:
                $val = $no/10000000;
                $val = round($val, 2);
                $finalval =  $val ." Cr";
                break;
            case 9:
                $val = $no/10000000;
                $val = round($val, 2);
                $finalval =  $val ." Cr";
                break;

            default:
                echo "";
        }
        return $finalval;

    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn't really this function, since numbers 5.4 and 5.40 are the same number, so either you need to apply formatting here, or in the place where you're using the results. Check the difference of these 2:

```
echo round(540000/100000, 2);
```

vs

```
echo sprintf("%2.2f", round(540000/100000, 2));
```

The second one will show 2 decimals, since that's defined in the format. You don't really need the round either if you use sprintf, it will round the number to the specified format.

```
echo sprintf("%2.2f", 555555 / 100000);
```

Answer (score -1):

this could help what you are expecting.

```
number_format($val/10000000,2); //for Crore convertion
```